# when nth root of matrices exists?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

We know that for any matrix $A\in M_m(\mathbb C)$ and any natural number $n$, we can find a matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$  such that $B^n=A$. Now, assume that  $F$ is a arbitrary algebraically closed field Is it true that for any matrix $A\in M_m(F)$ and any natural number $n$, we can find a matrix $B\in M_n(F)$  such that $B^n=A$?

Answer (score 4):

A criterion for a nonsingular matrix $A$ in $M_n(K)$ for any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ to have an $n$-th root in $M_n(K)$ has been given by Gabriëlle ten Have in the article [Structure of the nth roots of a matrix](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959390127A). In Theorem $1$, page $62$ it is proved that $A$ has an $n$-th root in $M_n(K)$ if and only if there are nonnegative integers
$b_{i1},\ldots ,b_{in}$ such that $d_i=\sum_k b_{ik}n_{ik}$ for $i=1,\ldots ,t$. Here the notation comes from a block decomposition of $A$ and other polynomial invarinats defined before. This Theorem could be applied for the case of $F$ with divisible multiplicative group $(F^{\times},\cdot)$.

Comment: Can we extend the above question by saying that when $m,n$  are arbitrary natural number,  $F$ is a field and for any $A\in M_m(F)$ there exists $B\in M_m(F)$ such that $B^n=A$, then $F^*$ is a divisible group.

Comment: Dear, prof.  Dietrich Burde, 
It seems that your  prove is wrong. Since for a field $F$,  when $F^*$ is divisible,  it is not necessary that $F(a)^*$ be adivisible group.

Comment: "it seems your proof is wrong"? I am sorry, but I did not prove anything. Ten Have proved this theorem. So if these conditions are not met, then $A$ does not have an $n$-th root, right?

Comment: In the last sentences  of your answer, you say  "This Theorem could be applied for the case of $F$ with divisible multiplicative group". What is the difference between  a divisible filed and an arbitrary field to use the  Have's  Theorem?

Comment: There is no difference. Have's theorem is for *all* fields $F\subseteq \mathbb{C}$. So we can apply it to all such fields $F$, which satisfy your assumption  that $F^*$ is divisible.